# Tooltip and RaphaelJS

Tags: jquery, tooltip, graphael

I would like to create a tooltip on the rectangle and the tooltip remains the same when I'm on the text, as in the background.
I use the library and jquery RaphaelJS (tooltip).

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById("canvas_schema"),550,300);


    var rectangle2 = paper.rect(130, 75, 140,40,15);
    var texte = paper.text(200, 90, "Tarification et souscription\nweb");

    rectangle2.attr({fill:"0.0-white:5-yellow:100"});
    rectangle2.animate({"stroke-width":0});


    texte.mouseover(function(){
        rectangle2.animate({
        fill:"0.0-white:5-red:100",
        "stroke-width":0,
        title:"hello"});});

    texte.mouseout(function(){
        rectangle2.animate({
        fill:"0.0-white:5-yellow:100"});});

    rectangle2.mouseover(function(){
        this.animate({
        fill:"0.0-white:5-red:100"});});

    rectangle2.mouseout(function(){
        this.animate({
        fill:"0.0-white:5-yellow:100"});});

    $(rectangle2.node).qtip({ 
                content: { text: 'ANTENIA<br>Solution Progicielle' },
                style:'mystyle',
                position: {
                    corner: {
                        target: 'topRight',
                        tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
                    }
                }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ua3Pg/
i don't know how to use raphaelJS and jquery on jsfiddle.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a method without using JQuery. You can call a "tooltip drawing" function from [element.hover()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.hover) event

```
function draw_tooltip(object, show, text, x, y) {
if(show == 0) {
    popup.remove();
    popup_txt.remove();
    transparent_txt.remove();
    return;
}
//draw text somewhere to get its dimensions and make it transparent
transparent_txt = rph.text(100,100, text).attr({fill: "transparent"});

//get text dimensions to obtain tooltip dimensions
var txt_box = transparent_txt.getBBox();

//draw text
popup_txt = rph.text(x+txt_box.width, y-txt_box.height-5, text).attr({fill: "black",font: "20px sans-serif"});

var bb = popup_txt.getBBox();

//draw path for tooltip box
popup = rph.path( 
                // 'M'ove to the 'dent' in the bubble
                "M" + (x) + " " + (y) +
                // 'v'ertically draw a line 5 pixels more than the height of the text
                "v" + -(bb.height+5) + 
                // 'h'orizontally draw a line 10 more than the text's width
                "h" + (bb.width+10) +
                // 'v'ertically draw a line to the bottom of the text
                "v" + bb.height + 
                // 'h'orizontally draw a line so we're 5 pixels fro thge left side
                "h" + -(bb.width+5) +
                // 'Z' closes the figure
                "Z").attr( {fill: "yellow"} );

//finally put the text in front
popup_txt.toFront();

}

var rph = Raphael(10, 50, 600, 300);
var x = 40, y = 40;
var tooltip_x = 60, tooltip_y = 60;
var display_text = "Hello";
rph.rect(x,y,60,40).attr({fill: "red"})
               .data({"x":x,"y":y})
               .hover(function () {
                    draw_tooltip(this, 1, display_text, tooltip_x, tooltip_y);
                },
                function() {
                    draw_tooltip(this,0);
                });
```

Here is an working example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WXbp9/)

I dont quite understand what you mean by "the tooltip remains the same when I'm on the text, as in the background" but in the code above you can change the text, tooltip coordinates, text color and tooltip background color.

**NOTE :** The element.hover() would work anywhere on the rectangle only if it's **filled** with some color. Otherwise you will be able to see tooltip only when you hover on the rectangle edges.

Comment: hi,
thank you you for your answer it helps me a lot.
I set you an example of my problem. When I pass the text tooltip disappears.
http://jsfiddle.net/eZAC9/

Comment: how about if we drag rph.rect, is the tooltip will follow the rect?